# How to pass dynamic parameters in curl request

Tags: shell, curl, post

I am passing dynamic value to testing method and executing the curl request. There is an issue with $PARAMETERS.

When I execute the following method, I get error as below

Error:-

```
curl: option -F: requires parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Function:-

```
testing() {

local URL=$1
local HTTP_TYPE=$2
local PARAMETERS=$3

# store the whole response with the status at the and
HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -w "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X $HTTP_TYPE $URL $PARAMETERS)

echo $HTTP_RESPONSE
}

URL='https://google.com'
HTTP_TYPE='POST'
PARAMETERS="-F 'name=test' -F 'query=testing'"


result=$(testing $URL $HTTP_TYPE $PARAMETERS)
```

FYI, above is a sample method and am using shell script. Kindly tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing multiple command arguments in your 3rd argument, shell will do splitting as you are using unquoted variable inside your function.

You should better use shell array to store `PARAMETERS` argument.

Have your function as:

```
testing() {
   local url="$1"
   local httpType="$2"

   shift 2 # shift 2 times to discard first 2 arguments
   local params="$@" # store rest of them in a var

   response=$(curl -s -w "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X "$httpType" "$url" "$params")
   echo "$response"
}
```

and call it as:

```
url='https://google.com'
httpType='POST'

params=(-F 'name=test' -F 'query=testing')
result=$(testing "$url" "$httpType" "${params[@]}")
```

Additionally you should avoid using all-caps variable names in your shell script to avoid clashes with env variables.

---

In case you're not using `bash`, you can also use:

```
params="-F 'name=test' -F 'query=testing'"
result=$(testing "$url" "$httpType" "$params")
```

[Code Demo](http://rextester.com/YKDD93746)

Comment: I am getting "Syntax error: "(" unexpected" in this line - PARAMETERS=(-F 'name=test' -F 'query=testing')

Comment: I am using shell script only for all my script files. I can't change to bash. It will affect my whole scripting.

Comment: Check edited answer though changing `sh` to `bash` usually doesn't break anything.

Comment: I am getting sample.sh: 421: local: -F: bad variable name
sample.sh: 421: sample.sh: 'name: bad variable name in this line local params=$3

Comment: But there is no `local params=$3` in my answer. You will need to copy/paste my suggested function code as well from answer.

Comment: I get error as "Reason: <pre> Missing required argument: value</pre>. "  after updation of code. I believe My API application requests accepting like this only -F "name=limit" -F "value=1000" instead of -F 'name=limit' -F 'value=1000'. I am not sure what is the exact issue here.

Comment: You can also reverse the quotes to make it: `params='-F "name=test" -F "query=testing"'`

Comment: Still it doesn't solve. See here < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [270 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 400 Missing required argument: value
< Date: Mon, 07 Aug 2017 06:21:14 GMT
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 349
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
{ [349 bytes data]
* Closing connection 0

Comment: I am passing like this '-F "name=limit" -F "value=800"'

Comment: [It works well here in demo](http://rextester.com/YKDD93746) and on my shell as well.

Comment: You should edit the question and copy/paste your latest script. Also try executing your script in bash for *testing purpose*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151234/discussion-between-karan-and-anubhava).

Comment: My curl request works manually when I hit PUT request with parameters.

Comment: Can you join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151235/anubhave-and-karan